solc: import defaults to cwd?
Would appreciate an explanation why the first solc call doesn't fail.
# downloaded from https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
$ ls *.sol
IERC20.sol  IERC20Metadata.sol
# metadata interface expects erc20 to reside in the parent dir
$ grep import IERC20Metadata.sol
import {IERC20} from "../IERC20.sol";
# succesfully generates abi, even though there's no ../IERC20.sol
$ solc IERC20Metadata.sol --abi > /dev/null && echo $?
0
$ rm IERC20.sol
$ solc IERC20Metadata.sol --abi > /dev/null
Error: Source "IERC20.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> IERC20Metadata.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import {IERC20} from "../IERC20.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Thanks!
